# FileNotFoundException thrown when file exists

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run this code,

```
public static void read_all_lines(){
    String file_name = "input.txt";
    File input_file = new File(file_name);
    Scanner in_file = null;
    try{
        in_file = new Scanner(input_file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: This file doesn't exist");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while(in_file.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in_file.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in_file.close();
}
```

That is supposed to read all lines in a .txt file and print them on the screen the FileNotFoundException is thrown. It catches it and prints out the error message with no problem. But the file does exist, I made two files input and input.txt, but the exception is still thrown.
[This is the file directory where the files and project are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkdm8.png)

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the file, like "C:\\folderA\\folderB\\input.txt";

Comment: I will try that right now and get back with an update

Comment: What is the current working directory?

Comment: Can you explain @JohannesKuhn? We haven't mentioned it so far in my class. If you mean the directory to the file it is fairly long, but if it is code then I'm afraid I haven't learned that.

Comment: Where is the file located relative to where you are executing the program file?  Try adding `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir");` to your code, it will tell you the "working" directory, this will need to be the same as the directory the file is stored in for it to work

Comment: @MadProgrammer the working directory is C:\Users\user\Documents\school Documents\Spring 2018\Programming 2\Guided Exercises\Guided Exercise 4\Guided Exercise 4 (The first one is a folder with all relative teaching materials and the second is the actual project itself. I think I figured out where I messed up at, my brain went back to python's file handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, the program seems to be in the folder "Guided Exercise 4" where the text files are outside that folder. If this is the case then either move the text files into the same folder as the program or `File input_file = new File("..\\" + file_name);` to reference the file in the parent directory. But I would recommend the moving the text files.

Comment: Yea I figured that out and proceeded to hate myself for it. I just moved the files as a fix.

Answer (score 1):

The files were not in the right area. Using `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` given by MadProgrammer I found what directory the program needed the files in and corrected the issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19176650)

Comment: @DanielCheung This is the author.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Oh, you must know that's SO's automated comment for the reviewing process. I didn't change it. My fault.